# Mono human readable GC statistics in runtime

Tags: mono, garbage-collection, profiling

Is there a Mono profiler mode similar to Java -Xloggc?

I would like to see a human readable GC report while my application is running. Currently Mono can be run with --profile=log option but the output is in binary format and every time I need to run mprof-report to read it. The output file also contains a lot of info which is not interesting for me.

I tried to reduce the file size by specifying heapshot=14400000ms to collect statistics every few hours but it didn't help a lot. In a week I had few gigabytes log.

I also tried to use "sample" profiler but the overhead was too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mono's [trace filters](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/logging-runtime-events/#trace-filters) for this. Just set the `MONO_LOG_MASK` to `gc` and lower the `MONO_LOG_LEVEL`. Then run your app normally and you will get the human-readable GC statistics while your app is running:

```
$ export MONO_LOG_MASK=gc
$ export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug
$ mono ... # run your application normally ..
...
# notice the human readable GC output
mono: GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) pause 26.00ms, total 26.06ms, bridge 0.00ms major 31472K/0K los 1575K/0K
Mono: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 2.30ms, total 2.35ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 31456K major 31456K los 5135K
Mono: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 2.43ms, total 2.45ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 31456K major 31456K los 8097K
Mono: GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) pause 1.80ms, total 1.82ms, bridge 0.00ms promoted 31472K major 31472K los 11425K
```